# How to label subfloats in the following environment

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats, labels

The information on how to label subimages is vast. However, all solutions tend to be very tailored and not generally applicable. I have spent a lot of time having 6 subfloats placed nicely, and I would like to label them accordingly without changing the code too much due to the timely challenge of getting it right again.

Right now the code is

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.53\textwidth]{plot1LVS.png}}
\label{10first}
\hfill    
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.53\textwidth]{plotLVS2.png}}
\label{10second}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.53\textwidth]{plotLVS4.png}}
\label{10third}
\hfill  
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.53\textwidth]{plotlvs3.png}}
\label{10fourth}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.53\textwidth]{plotLVS5.png}}
\label{10fifth}
\hfill  
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.53\textwidth]{plotLVS6.png}}
\caption{text}
\end{figure}
```

I have many packages, but I believe the relevant ones are

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
```

This code is not ideal, it produces error messages that I have an overfull hbox, but it let me get away with it and compiles what I want. I know this is not sustainable but I did not manage to fix it. I think it is because all lines start at the same place without indent.

The main problem (might be related to the above) is that referencing the subimages only gives the symbol "??".

I read a bit about cleaverref and tried to use that userpackage with no success. But all solutions I come across is again very tailored to a very specific piece of code making it challenging for beginners to apply.

Any help and input on how I can label the subimages (or subfloats) is very welcomed.

Comment: You should not load `subcaption` along with `subfig`. You're using syntax from the latter. The `\label` has to go within the argument to `\subfloat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your setup.

The main one is that you're loading `subcaption` along with `subfig`. Use just one of them. Since `\subfloat` is defined by `subfig`, just load this one.

Second point: if you have images that are more than a half of the text width, you can't have two of them in the same line.

Third point: the `[H]` specifier with such a big `figure` environment will most likely produce very bad page breaks.

Fourth point: leave a blank line between pairs of figures.

Fifth point: the `\label` should go inside the argument to `\subfloat`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image}\label{10first}}
\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image}\label{10second}}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image}\label{10third}}
\hfill  
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image}\label{10fourth}}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image}\label{10fifth}}
\hfill  
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image}\label{10sixth}}

\caption{text}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]